# How changes made on an object in a list affect all elements

Tags: python

Here is my problem,

```
from Link import Link

def generateCompartibleLinks(linksList):
    count =0
    updatedList =[]
    for i,item in enumerate(linksList):
        link = linksList[i];
        for j,item in enumerate(linksList):
            if not linksList[i].sharesNode(linksList[j]):
                link.addCompartibleLink(linksList[j])
        updatedList.append(link)
        print len(updatedList[i].compartibleLinks)
    return updatedList

link1 = Link("a","b",5)
link2 =Link("b","c",1)
link3 = Link("d","b",3)
link4 =Link("d","c",2)

list1 = [link2,link1,link3,link4]

list1 = generateCompartibleLinks(list1)

for link in list1:
    print str(len(link.compartibleLinks))+" : "+link.getLinkInfo()
```

I expect each of the links (link1,link2,link3, link4) to have a different set of compartibleLinks but once a change is made on any element in the list it's reflected on each of them which is not what I want.
Here is class Link.

```
class Link(object):
    sendNode =None
    rcvNode =None
    timesToSchedule =1
    isScheduled = False
    compartibleLinks = []
    def __init__(self,sendNode,rcvNode,timesToschedule):
        self.sendNode=sendNode
        self.rcvNode = rcvNode
        self.timesToSchedule =timesToschedule

    def reduceTimeToSchedule(self):
        self.timesToSchedule -=1
        if  self.timesToSchedule<=0:
             self.timesToSchedule=0

    def needsToschedule(self):
        if  self.timesToSchedule==0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    def addCompartibleLink(self,link):
        self.compartibleLinks.append(link)
    def isCompartible(self,link):
        return any(l == link for l in self.compartibleLinks);
        #if the link is not found in the set.
        return False;
    def sharesNode(self,link):
        return (self.sendNode==link.sendNode or self.rcvNode==link.rcvNode or self.rcvNode==link.sendNode or self.sendNode==link.rcvNode)
    def getLinkInfo(self):
        return 'sender: '+ self.sendNode+" , rec:"+self.rcvNode
```

I have tried to look at various solutions that seem related to my problem but nothing really works for me.

Comment: That's because you have just the one list per class, shared among instances. See the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks let me check it out!

Comment: Thank you! You have saved my day. had spent days messing up!

Answer (score -1):

If I correctly understand what you're asking, then I suggest you use the built-in [map](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) function that is used to apply a given function to an iterable(i.e. your list). Of course you have to modify the generateCompatibleLinks function to accept a link and not a whole list.

Comment: Could I get an explanation as to why my answer was downvoted? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thanks for your support. I was able to identify the problem. It was about intitializing the compartibleLinks list outside the constructor. I didn't down you :-). I appreciate your help.